Issue with LL(1) Grammar Transformation – Parser Generator Error
I am working on transforming a grammar into LL(1) form, but when I try to use an online LL(1) Parser Generator, it reports an error. I have followed the standard procedure for the transformation, but I can't seem to find the issue. Here is the grammar I'm working with:
MAIN ::= STMT
MAIN ::= FLIST 
MAIN ::= "

FLIST ::= FDEF FLIST'
FLIST' ::= FLIST 
FLIST' ::= "

FDEF ::= def id ( PARLIST ) { STMTLIST }

PARLIST ::= int id PARLIST'
PARLIST' ::= , int id PARLIST' 
PARLIST' ::= "

VARLIST ::= id VARLIST'
VARLIST' ::= , VARLIST 
VARLIST' ::= "

STMT ::= int VARLIST ;
STMT ::= ATRIBST ;
STMT ::= PRINTST ;
STMT ::= RETURNST ;
STMT ::= IFSTMT ;
STMT ::= { STMTLIST } ;
STMT ::= ; 

ATRIBST ::= id := ATREXPR
ATREXPR ::= EXPR 
ATREXPR ::= FCALL

FCALL ::= id ( PARLISTCALL )

PARLISTCALL ::= id PARLISTCALL'
PARLISTCALL' ::= , PARLISTCALL 
PARLISTCALL' ::= "

PRINTST ::= print EXPR

RETURNST ;:= return RETURNEXPR
RETURNEXPR ::= id
RETURNEXPR ::= "

IFSTMT ::= if ( EXPR ) STMT IFSTMT'
IFSTMT' ::= else STMT 
IFSTMT' ::= "

STMTLIST ::= STMT STMTLIST'
STMTLIST' ::= STMT STMTLIST' 
STMTLIST' ::= "

EXPR ::= NUMEXPR EXPR'
EXPR' ::= < NUMEXPR
EXPR' ::= <= NUMEXPR
EXPR' ::= > NUMEXPR
EXPR' ::= >= NUMEXPR
EXPR' ::= == NUMEXPR
EXPR' ::= <> NUMEXPR
EXPR' ::= "

NUMEXPR ::= TERM NUMEXPR'
NUMEXPR' ::= + TERM NUMEXPR'
NUMEXPR' ::= - TERM NUMEXPR'
NUMEXPR' ::= "

TERM ::= FACTOR TERM'
TERM' ::= * FACTOR TERM'
TERM' ::= / FACTOR TERM'
TERM' ::= "

FACTOR ::= num 
FACTOR ::= ( NUMEXPR) 
FACTOR ::= id

I use this parser: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring20/cos320/LL1/

This error appear in the table.
I want the parser to work.

Both EXPR and FCALL may begin with an id. Therefore, the grammar is not LL(1) and the parser generator is unable to decide whether it should try to parse EXPR or FCALL. Here's a minimal grammar that illustrates the same issue:
A ::= id ( )
A ::= id

There are three possibilities for amending the situation: introduce a symbol table, utilize special lexical conventions or rephrase the grammar.

With a symbol table, you distinguish function names from variable names (e.g. func_id vs var_id) using a table containing the names and types of all variables defined in the source code so far; this is discussed fairly extensively elsewhere.
Alternatively, you could establish (lexical) requirements for function or variable names to distinguish them from one another, e.g. prefixing all variables with $.
The last option is to remove the offending ATREXPR ::= FCALL and/or FACTOR ::= id rules and reimplement them in an unambiguous manner. One possible example follows; it is roughly equivalent to the sample code, except function calls will be permitted within expressions.

FACTOR ::= id OPTPARLISTCALL
OPTPARLISTCALL ::= ( PARLISTCALL )
OPTPARLISTCALL ::= ''


This is a example of how can I refactor this ?
ATRIBST ::= id := ATREXPR
ATREXPR ::= id ATREXPR'
ATREXPR' ::= := EXPR
ATREXPR' ::= ( PARLISTCALL )

It's probably faster for you to just try it with the tool; note that the current input token is in the column header and that the conflicting rules are highlighted in red. If you (by any means, including the ones in my answer) remove the conflicts caused by that token in the left-most expansions of the conflicting rules, you will have a valid grammar.
